# Proteccion de credenciales

Tags: mysql, c#

Tengo la siguiente pregunta relacionada a la proteccion de credenciales y recomendaciones de proteccion.

El contexto es el siguiente, acabo de heredar un proyecto en el cual tengo que consultar y extraer informacion de diferentes servidores cabe mencionar que todos los servidores tienen la misma arquitectura de la base de datos y tablas como tambien recalcar que solo tengo acceso en modo lectura a dichos servidores no puedo crear en ellos procedimientos almacenados, vistas etc. El acceso (usuario y password) es el mismo para todos los servidores. Actualmente esta aplicacion la tengo solo en mi PC, pero ha llegado la hora de distribuir dicha aplicacion el problema con ello es que para consultar los servidores la persona que trabajo en el proyecto tiene listadas todas las IP en un archivo de texto y el usuario y contraseña lo manda en un String desde la aplicacion, estas credenciales de acceso no las debe de tener nadie he visto metodos de encriptacion desde el App.Config y ofuscamiento de codigo que tan seguro es usar estos tipos de metodos?
Hay mayor seguridad si vinculo todos estos servidores a un servidor local y creo claves de acceso en este servidor tambien aqui podria crear SP, vistas etc pero no se que tanto merme el rendimiento de estos usando servidores vinculados.

El proyecto es un desarrollo en C# y MySQL.

Este es el esquema actual que tengo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco las recomencadiones que puedan aportarme.

Saludos

DS

Comment: Y el contexto de la aplicación cual es?? Porque si es de uso interno, y la información no es "secreta" y esas cuentas solo tienen acceso de lectura, yo no veo tanto problema en el asunto

Comment: @Yussef
el problema es que los accesos estan restringidos muy pocos usuarios tienen acceso a la db, cada localidad tiene una aplicacion cliente (diferente a la mia) esta aplicacion constantemente esta enviado solicitudes y requriendo informacion al servidor (mi aplicacion) es solo extraccion de datos para realizar reportes y dashboards, es decir aunque el user es de solo lectura si se obtienen estas credenciales pueden crear sus propias consultas y enviar consultas NO optimizadas y mermar el rendimiento del servidor cosa que ya ha pasado y han tumbado produccion.